# Multiply found text in sed - is it possible?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

This is what I have:

```
echo -e "a\t4\nb\t7\nc\t2\nd\t12\n" | sed -rn 's/(.*)\t([0-9]*)$/\2\t\1\1\1\t/p'

4   aaa  
7   bbb 
2   ccc 
12  ddd
```

This I want:

```
4   aaaa    
7   bbbbbbb  
2   cc  
12  dddddddddddd
```

Is this possible in sed only or I have to use some other tools?

Comment: It would certainly be *simpler* in other tools - perl for example has a string repetition operator ex. `printf '%c\t%d\n' a 4 b 7 c 2 d 12 | perl -F'\t' -lne 'print join "\t", $F[1], $F[0] x $F[1]'`

Comment: I would go with @steeldriver perl script for sure.

Comment: You are right -- points up for Perl. :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really totally pure [`sed`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/sed.1plan9.html), but rather with setting the flag `e` which allows for embedding shell commands and executing them and allows for **risky** command injection as well so know that one and do (*if you have to*) on your own risk.

Not really my preferred way either but you asked for it.

That said, you can do it with something like this:

```
$ echo -ne "a\t4\nb\t7\nc\t2\nd\t12\n" |
sed -rn "s/(.*)\t([0-9]*)$/bash -c \"printf '%s\t' \2; printf '\1%.0s' {1..\2}\"/ep"
4   aaaa
7   bbbbbbb
2   cc
12  dddddddddddd
```

Comment: You could avoid the extra (bash) shell by using `seq` in place of the brace expansion in the replacement: `printf '%s\t' \2; printf '\1%.0s' \$(seq \2)`

Comment: Yes, @steeldriver that would offer more portability … Although, starting an extra shell/sub-shell seems unavoidable both ways.

Comment: Raffa, I can do it to in Python or Bash, but I thought sed could be more elegant way. You are right that Perl is most elegant by now, but I do not know it much. I guess that awk could also do the job. I prefer to know less programming languages deeper then to know many languages superficially. So thank you  all for nice jobs. :-)